# "X3D" : isn't display any thing when use the ElevationGrid

Tags: 3d, x3d, x3dom, helix-3d-toolkit, javafx-3d

I use this example but the problem isn't display any thing when use the ElevationGrid but when use others example for example all shapes its work normal can anybody have any information's or suggestions to me because i must draw the terrain "earth"? 
[this the html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFjXx.jpg)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started with X3D - Step 1</title>
    <meta name='description' content='Getting started with X3D in 3 easy steps. Step 1: HTML5 page.' />
    <meta name='keywords' content='x3d, x3dom, getting started, tutorial, easy' />
    <meta encoding="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="getting-started.css" />
    <script src="http://x3dom.org/release/x3dom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://x3dom.org/release/x3dom.css" />
</head>


<body class='page'>
    <div class='page-header'>
        <h1>Getting Started with X3D</h1>
        <h2>Step 1 &ndash; HTML5 Page</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='page-content'>
        <p>This is the initial page. It consists of standard HTML5 tags and contains no X3D. The box below defines the area to be used for the X3D scene.</p>
        <div class='scene'>
            <div class='x3d-content'>
            <x3d x='0px' y='0px' width='1000px' height='700px'>
    <scene>
            <viewpoint position='0 0 10' ></viewpoint>
              <shape>
                <appearance>
                    <Material diffuseColor='0.4 0.4 0.1'></Material>
                </appearance>
                <ElevationGrid DEF='ElevationGrid' creaseAngle='1.57' xDimension='9' zDimension='9' xSpacing='1.0' zSpacing='1.0' solid='FALSE' height='0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 3.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 2.0, 4.5, 2.5, 1.0, 1.5, 0.5,1.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.5, 5.5, 3.5, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.5, 3.5, 4.0, 2.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.5, 0.5,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0'></ElevationGrid>
             </shape>
          </scene>
        </x3d>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the code as code, not as an image...

Answer (score 1):

`ElevationGrid` is only contained in the "full" version (x3dom-**full**.js)

So just write:

```
<script src="http://x3dom.org/release/x3dom-full.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://x3dom.org/release/x3dom.js"></script>
```